# Hacer deploy de aplicacion JSF en Bluemix

Tags: java, jsf, ibm-bluemix

Tengo una simple aplicacion en JSF la cual quiero probar en el servicio de Bluemix de IBM para ello estoy haciendo pruebas en el servidor local que proporciona bluemix para java y para facilitarme las cosas me instalado el plugin de Bluemix para eclipse.

Cuando prueblo la aplicacion en el servidor de apache tomcat funciona bien pero cuando lo pruebo en el de bluemix localmente me muestra el siguiente mensaje.

```
  Context Root Not Found
```

Imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Informacion por consola(editado).

```
    Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 17.0.0.2/wlp-1.0.17.cl170220170523-1818) on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/17.0.0.2/lafiles/en.html
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKI0001I: The CORBA name server is now available at corbaloc:iiop:localhost:2809/NameService.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/FirstJSF/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application FirstJSF started in 12.533 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [servlet-3.1, beanValidation-1.1, ssl-1.0, jndi-1.0, jca-1.7, ejbPersistentTimer-3.2, appSecurity-2.0, j2eeManagement-1.1, jdbc-4.1, wasJmsServer-1.0, jaxrs-2.0, javaMail-1.5, cdi-1.2, webProfile-7.0, jcaInboundSecurity-1.0, jpa-2.1, jsp-2.3, ejbLite-3.2, managedBeans-1.0, jsf-2.2, ejbHome-3.2, jaxws-2.2, localConnector-1.0, jsonp-1.0, el-3.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, concurrent-1.0, appClientSupport-1.0, ejbRemote-3.2, javaee-7.0, jaxb-2.2, mdb-3.2, jacc-1.5, batch-1.0, ejb-3.2, json-1.0, jaspic-1.1, jpaContainer-2.1, distributedMap-1.0, websocket-1.1, wasJmsSecurity-1.0, wasJmsClient-2.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
[WARNING ] JSFG0853W: The MyFaces JSF Implementation is selected for FirstJSF but a Sun RI ConfigureListener is also registered.
[WARNING ] JSFG0853W: The MyFaces JSF Implementation is selected for FirstJSF but a Sun RI ConfigureListener is also registered.
[WARNING ] SRVE0274W: Error while adding servlet mapping for path-->/faces/*, wrapper-->ServletWrapper[Faces Servlet:[/faces/*]], application-->FirstJSF.
```

Editado

Version de servidor de Tomcat : Tomcat 9.0

Version de servidor que proporciona BlueMix: [WebSphere Application Server 17.0.0.2](https://developer.ibm.com/assets/wasdev/#asset/runtimes-wlp-javaee7)

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>FirstJSF</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <async-supported>false</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
        /faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Enlace del proyecto completo: https://github.com/crack81/firstJSF

Comment: ¿Eso te sale cuando entras a `http://localhost:9080/Hello/`?

Comment: Si y aunque coloque la ruta completa continua el problema,  la aplicacion funciona bien en tomcat.

Comment: Es que justo despúes de levantarte el contexto te envía este mensaje `Web application removed (default_host): http://localhost:9080/Hello/` aparente sin nada más que la advertencia de las versiones de JSF, que no me parece que sea la causa. ¿Editas el POST y pones las versiones de Tomcat y Bluemix?

Comment: @yorodm Listo agrege las version de los servidores que estoy usando y actualize la informacion que me proporciona por consola.

Comment: puedes mostrar tu web.xml si ha implementado un archivo WAR, la aplicación web es accesible bajo la raíz de contexto definida en el archivo ibm-web-ext.xml incorporado. Si el archivo ibm-web-ext.xml no existe o no especifica la raíz de contexto, la aplicación es accesible en el contexto raíz.

Comment: @SoftMolina  he puesto el enlace del  proyecto.

Comment: Acabo de revisar las fuentes de tu proyecto y no veo fuentes Java en él (no existe la carpeta src, pero sí la carpeta target que es una carpeta que nunca debería commitearse). Además, la estructura del pom.xml es un poco extraña, como si tu IDE (posiblemente Eclipse) lo hubiese moldeado a su gusto.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza La verdad no coloque nada de codigo java creo por eso no aperece src, lo queria mantener lo mas basico posible para ver porque me mostraba el mensaje de Context Root Not Found, ahora modifique el proyecto y agrege un managedbean y ahora ya se puede ver la carpeta src con respecto al pom.xml la verdad no sabria decirte si esta raro, para el proyecto cree una aplicacion  dinamic web proyect y para que soportara maven seleccion la opcion de convertir a maven que proporciona eclipse lo demas simplemente son algunas caracteristicas que me fui incluyendo como el soporte de primefaces